# Why doesn't python have built-in function mean()?

Tags: python, function, math

Whilst one can call `min()` or `max()` on their own, function `mean()` has to rely on other imported packages such as Numpy, that is, `np.mean()`. If the concepts of **min** and **max** are *natural* for a scale/range, shouldn't it be the middle of the scale/range (that is, **mean**) considered as *natural* also? What is the underlying reason for this *inconsistency*? Please note this is not an opinion-based question, I do really like to know the reason for the *exclusion* of the `mean()` function from the base package.

Comment: If you're asking why `mean` isn't a builtin function, then you should probably ask the python devs about that.

Comment: @coldspeed, that's exactly what I meant to ask, but did not know to clarify with the term "built-in". This makes Python syntax somewhat inconsistent without builtin mean()!

Comment: @coldspeed Advising OP "ask the python devs" is unlikely to lead to greater understanding on their part. If you didn't just mean to make a joke at their expense, you probably need to more carefully state what you're getting at.

Comment: @RobertDodier it should've been obvious... But I was trying to get at the fact that this is not really appropriate to ask here, being mostly opinion based (the "why" part, at least).

Comment: @coldspeed Not obvious to OP, I suspect. If you think the question is too much about opinions, then probably better to just say so.

Comment: Thanks, @RobertDodier for pointing out @coldspeed's true intention. For someone inexperience like me, please be straightforward otherwise I would miss your underlying message. I can't understand why by asking question "why" would equate to an opinion based question? I do really want to know why/the underlying reason for ```mean()``` not to be included in the base package.

Answer (score 8):

It does have a `mean`, but it needs to be imported from [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html).

```
import statistics

numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
print( "mean is ", statistics.mean( numbers ) )
```

Which outputs:

```
mean is  2.5
```

There are a set of ["built-in" functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) for Python.  These functions can be called directly.  `min()` and `max()` fall into this category.  Other functions, "library functions" need to be explicitly imported before they can be used, `statistics.mean()` is a library function.

If you feel like this begs-the-question, "why have library functions?" - there are *hundreds* of library functions for Python.  It's inefficient to include them into the run-time for every program.  I've been programming python for more years than I care to remember, and yet I have *never* used `statistics.mean()` before this question.

Comment: Thanks, Kingsley! But I didn't have to import statistics to find docstring for min() and max()!

Comment: @Jason See also the Scipy and Numpy packages which have many related functions. A web search will find those packages and much information.

Comment: Thanks, @RobertDodier for your advice. My question is why ```mean()``` has to rely on other packages (Scipy, Numpy etc) to work (that is, ```np.mean```) whilst ```min()``` and ```max()``` can be called by their own?

Comment: @Jason - I added some notes about library functions.  Maybe this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Kingsley! Your additional info does really help. But as you pointed out, there are hundred of libraries, and each of them has to define their own mean function, wouldn't it be inefficient then? Btw, I really like your comprehensive answer!

Comment: Say you have a library for a `screen` and a library for a `paper-plotter`.  The `draw()` function would do different things for the different libraries.

Comment: @Jason The reason for some functions being built-in and others being in libraries is a consequence of the history of Python. Originally Python wasn't much of a data-processing language, and later that became important. Choices were made early on in the development of Python to make some things built-in which seemed important at the time; `mean` wasn't one of them. Every language is like that -- choices are made in the language design to emphasize what seemed important at the time. If you study the history of various languages you'll see what different people have considered important.

Comment: @RobertDodier. did you mean originally Python *was* (instead of *wasn't*) more of a data-processing language (that's why it didn't include `mean()` as `mean` is a mathematical concept)? Although your explanation is not a concrete proof., I think I'd like to accept it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@Kingsley has a good point, but it would may well be a little easier with doing the logic of it:

```
numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
print("The mean is", sum(numbers)/len(numbers))
```

It reproduces:

```
The mean is 2.5
```

Comment: But that would go against the spirit of Python for short and sweet? That is, instead of ```mean(numbers)```, we have to make do with ```sum(numbers)/len(numbers)```?